# Texture not applying on .obj file in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I exported .stl file and converted to .obj and imported in Unity. Then, I imported some material from asset store. Then, I try to apply the material to the models that I imported, but the textures doesn't apply.

I tried changing the shader options, checking the lighting options. But, i may checked wrong

[image: Unity Screenshot]

Comment: Try dragging and dropping that material onto the object itself?

Comment: yeah, but it doesn't work..

Comment: Add UV Mapping to mesh with 3D software.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that can be going on here, as stated in another answer it could be your tiling

no matter on which coordinate system you are using your texture will always have a UV range of 0 -> 1, however depending on the system your UV's will be one of these 2:

0,0 at bottom left, and 1,1 at top right or

0,0 at top left, and 1,1 at bottom right.  (NOTE: this is in reference to where the UV's fall on the texture, not the UV's in related to the verts on your model.)

so when your tiling is set to 0,0 you are saying uv.x * 0, and uv.y * 0, this will default all of your UV's to a value of 0, after the math the shader uses to determine which color to use for that texel, it will always be the same.

A quick example where this can happen would be with tiling, since we are scaling the UV values (Which shrinks the texture view when tiling > 0) if our vert has a value of (0.73, 0.82), and we are scaling by 2 that value would turn into (1.46, 1.64).

Now per our example if you use a value > 1, there are 2 things to be weary of when it comes to texturing, they are your UV values, and your TextureWrap Settings.  Since all textures are based off of a 0 -> 1 range, a value of 1.46 is greater.  The way this is handled depends on your TextureWrapMode settings in the inspector of your texture.  You can read more on this at: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureWrapMode.html

To summarize though, if you want a tiled texture set this to Repeat, not doing so and using clamping, will clamp your UV's to 0 -> 1, anything larger then 1 will be set to one, and you are faced with the same circumstance as setting the tiling to 0.

In short, set your tiling to 1,1, and make sure your texture inspector settings are set correctly, for the use case.

My approach would be:  Setting the texture to repeat in the inspector, then adjusting the tiling until it looks good(Also tiling to much can make it all appear the same color as well).

This of course will only solve the issue if your model does have UV's assigned.  You can look up the OBJ format specification, and view the file with notepad to determine if it does have UV's setup.

Answer (score 0):

In the hierarchy, there should be another element inside your object. It has its own mesh renderer which overrides the mesh renderer of the parent object. If you change the material of that nested element, it should work ;)